# WinJS List GridLayout header above list

Tags: html, css, winjs

How to put header in listview with GridLayout.
When I put header above listview my header take some height and last row in listview is not showed, because of header.

I also found a way to set header in listview directly:

```
data-win-options="{ header: select('.header') }">
```

With this my header is positioned on the left side of list, not above the list, like normal header should be.
I did not see any example with listview GridLayout and header section above (for instance I wanna put search box and heading in header).

Any example of this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two solutions are here:

> 1) This is answer I get from Microsoft:
>
> In the list view the WinJS.UI.GridLayout's viewport is loaded
>   horizontally.
>   [image]
>   You need to change the viewport's orientation to vertical. You can do
>   this by attaching the event onloadingstatechanged event.
>
> ```
> args.setPromise(WinJS.UI.processAll().then(function () {
>                 listview.winControl.onloadingstatechanged = function myfunction() {
>                     if (listview.winControl.loadingState == "viewPortLoaded")
>                     {
>                         var viewport = listview.winControl.element.getElementsByClassName('win-viewport')[0];
>                         viewport.className = 'win-viewport win-vertical';
>                     }
>                 }
>             }));
> ```
>
> and change the class win-horizontal to win-vertical. 
>   [image]

2) Problem could be also solved adding standard html header and list below header, without data-win-options="{ header: select('.header') }" attribute.

In that case we need to calculate height of the list:

```
 .list {
    height: calc(100% - headerHeight);
 }
```